# Querying SQL for grouped data and receiving it in BizTalk?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, wcf, biztalk

I have a query that returns data organized by group.  I am wanting to have them come out in a grouped XML similar to the format below.  I am planning to pass it in as a XML message into BizTalk using the WCF-SQL port adapter.

Data:

```
ID  GroupID    Item ID    FileName  
1      1          1       File001.txt  
2      1          2       File001.txt   
3      2          3       File002.txt   
4      2          4       File002.txt   
5      2          5       File002.txt   
6      3          6       File003.txt   
7      3          7       File003.txt   
8     null        8       File004.txt   
9     null        9       File005.txt
```

XML Ouput (input to BizTalk)

```
<GroupInfo  ID=1  FileName=File001.txt>  
   <Items>
      <Item ID=1 />
      <Item ID=2 />
   </Items>
</GroupInfo>
<GroupInfo  ID=2  FileName=File002.txt>  
   <Items>
      <Item ID=3 />
      <Item ID=4 />
      <Item ID=5 />
   </Items>
</GroupInfo>
<GroupInfo  ID=3  FileName=File003.txt>  
   <Items>
      <Item ID=6 />
      <Item ID=7 />
   </Items>
</GroupInfo>
<GroupInfo  FileName=File004.txt>  
   <Items>
      <Item ID=8 />
   </Items>
</GroupInfo>
<GroupInfo  FileName=File005.txt>  
   <Items>
      <Item ID=9 />
   </Items>
</GroupInfo>
```

I'm not sure what to do to get the output in the required format.  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this, you would have to use FOR XML results from the Stored Procedure.

All documented here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx

In this case, you might find it easier to join the table to itself on GroupID as FOR XML AUTO will automatically create child records for the joined rows.